# How do I update user profile? Laravel-5

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-5, laravel-facade

Just want to start by saying I have no clue what I'm doing...
I have a user_info table that looks like this

```
    Schema::create('user_info', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->string('state');
        $table->string('zip');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->text('experience');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I'm having trouble creating the update controller which looks like this right now.

```
public function update(Request $request)
{

  $user = $request->user();
  $data['description'] = $request->input('description');
  $data['experience']=$request->input('experience');

  $user->user_info -> $data->save();
}
```

again...no clue what I'm doing...

and this be my form:

```
    <div class='col-md-10 well form-well'>
        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'PATCH', 'action'=> ['UserController@update', Request::user()->id]]) !!}
        <div class='row'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-md-2'>
                        {!! Form::label('description', 'About You')!!}
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-md-7'>
                        {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'rows'=>'3'])!!}
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-md-2'>
                        {!! Form::label('experience', 'Experience and Skills')!!}
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-md-7'>
                        {!! Form::text('experience', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>            
            {!! Form::submit('Save Changes',['class'=> 'btn btn-md btn-success']) !!}
            {!! Form::close()!!}
    </div>
```

Update: I was able to update it like this:

```
$user->user_info->description = $data['description'];
  $user->user_info->experience = $data['experience'];
  $user->user_info->save();
```

But is there a way I can do something like :

```
$user->user_info->$request::Input::all();
$user->user_info->save();
```

Comment: Well, that - `$user->user_info -> $data->save();` is a very strange line... Does page report about any errors ?

Comment: i get an error exception: array to string conversion.  How would it usually be written?

Comment: I have no experence in Laravel, however, it is pure PHP message. I would suggest to look through manuals how it should be done properly. Also I would suggest to try something like just `$data->save()` or `$user->user_info = $data->save();`.

Comment: I get this error when i try that `Call to a member function save() on a non-object`

Comment: Well, as of your latest update, you may try to loop through `$request->input(...)` and assign their values to `$user->user_info`, then commit it to `$user->user_info->save();`.

Comment: I suggest you to read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279435/what-does-mass-assignment-mean-in-laravel). The feature you asking is called *"mass assignment"*. Here is [general approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076156/how-to-mass-assign-an-update-in-laravel-4), but for laravel 4, however I think, that it might work for Laravel 5 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $User = User::with('user_info')->find($id);
  if(!$User) {
    return response('User not found', 404);
  }

  $UserInfo = $User->user_info;
  if(!$UserInfo) {
    $UserInfo = new UserInfo();
    $UserInfo->user_id = $id;
    $UserInfo->save();
  }

  try {
    $values = Input::only($UserInfo->getFillable());
    $UserInfo->update($values);
  } catch(Exception $ex) {
    return response($ex->getMessage(), 400);
  }
}
```

also in Your UserInfo model add this:

```
protected $fillable = array('description', 'experience');
public function getFillable() {
  return $this->fillable;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do mass assignment instead? Something like : ```UserInfo ->request::input->all()->save()->```

Comment: Also, my model includes address but that's to be submitted from another form.  I don't want to have to use a different controller action for it.

Comment: I get user info does not exist

Comment: Have You defined relation in User model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90669/discussion-between-num8er-and-jack-duong).

Comment: so i should probably do something like ``` if !UserInfo{ UserInfo->user_id=$id```?

Comment: i get an error saying Class 'App\Http\Controllers\UserInfo' not found

Comment: funny :) You see that UserInfo not found so in You controller file add: user App\UserInfo;

Comment: lol that is funny. but now i get this : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list' (SQL: update `user_info` set `_method` = PATCH, `_token` = '  Is it saying i don't have a token column in my model?

Comment: that's because You're sending Input::all() to update :)

Comment: Jack, have You checked?

Comment: yeah sorry it still doesn't work.  I'm still getting ```QLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list' (SQL: update `user_info` set `_method` = PATCH, `_token` = VKUWdhmhflCenZVpGGL7iJ4Wkx0SSAasflu4Vdl6, `description` = fsdf, `experience` = fsef, `3` = , `updated_at` = 2015-09-26 07:53:04)```

Comment: And I think one of the columns: '3' is the id number of the user.

Comment: have You added fillable to Your model?

Comment: is this line  ` $UserInfo = ($User->user_info)? $User->user_info : new UserInfo(); `  saying 'does user -> user_info exists? if not create one?'

Comment: yes, but now issue is when You're doing update(Input::all())

Comment: Yeah I added the fillable alreadyy.  I actually did this when I first made the model.

Comment: Now I'm not getting any errors, but its also not updating

Comment: I did var_dump(UserInfo->user_id) after the update and it returns null.